# procrun server crashes after few seconds

Tags: dll, procrun

I have a web application, using Spring-Boot. There is now a need for this application to use a custom dll (in house build dll file). There is nothing wrong with this dll, as we use it on our other applications, and have no problems with it.

To load the library in this new web application I'm writing, I have added the dll file to the procrun directory. This directory is on the library path, so that makes sense.

During startup I put in code to immediately load the dll, and also test some of its functionality. This works fine.

However, I have a timer, that schedules the execution of some functions, which may or may not include function calls to the dll.

At some point, about 10 minutes or so into execution, the service unexpected and seemingly without any valid reason, stops.

Although I try/catch exceptions at the appropriate logical places in code, there are no relevant log entries printed.

The Event Log shows something that reminds me of a null pointer exception:[image]

Another bread crumb is that the event log will print something about the dll_unload. (see picture)

I need some help figuring out why the service is failing/stopping.
Kind Regards.

EDIT: After about three days of debugging and scratching my head, I came upon a forum thread that explained that this problem has something to do with the manner in which the system releases the memory during garbage collection. It seems that the dll in question was being unloaded by the garbage collector, even though it could still be called at some time later - which of course was the cause of the service falling over.

To solve the problem, I put in a timer that would call a method in the dll at three minute intervals (on my system this would not impact performance). I know this solution is a hack, but it works for me.

Comment: Since you are talking about garbage collector: Is it possible that your application or this DLL is unmanaged code you are not aware of?

Comment: hi @WillyK. What do you mean by unmanaged code? As far as I know all the code, even the dlls have been written in-house (by our team itself).

Comment: The main purpose of "Managed code" like .NET applications is to minimize typical programming mistakes. In this case I think about the memory manager, which may move your data to another location in memory.

The common Windows API like CreateFile (from kernel32.dll) is "native code" that does not run under the "authority" of the .NET Framework. This what we call unmanaged code.

You may use unmanaged code in your managed .application, but you need to ensure that your data do not move in memory. 

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318664(v=vs.85).aspx